# wpf DataGridColumn width in Windows Clasic

Tags: windows, wpfdatagrid, datagridcolumn

I have DataGrid with many columns and it is vital to minimize used space. 
Data for this DataGrid is very random, somtimes column can be empty, somtimes filled with large numbers, so I decided not to specify column width.
I'm using Windows 7 Basic desktop setting (picture on the left) and it looks good, but some of my users uses Windows Clasic desktop settings (picture on the right) and columns is unnecesary wide.

"new users aren't allowed to post images" - so no pictures

Picture on the left: empty column with header "A", it's width is 5mm,
  column with embeded checkbox, width is 6mm
Picture on the right: empty column with header "A", it's width is 6mm 
  column with embedeb checkbox, width is 8mm

For my 20 columns it makes quit a place :(

What can I do to DataGridColumn width to make it tighter in Windows Classic?